# python list of tuple iteration for BWT decoding

Tags: python, list, indexing, duplicates, generator

input list:

```
list = [(a, 6), (e, 3), (e, 4), (g, 0), (m, 1), (s, 2), (s, 5)]
```

and I need to receive sorted list of tuples by 2nd value in tuple
but the second value in result should be index of tuple from previous list:

```
list1 = [[(g, 3), (m, 4), (s, 5), (e, 1), (e, 2), (s, 6), (a, 0)]]
```

and then somehow iterate starting from 1 element of list1 append the char to result and come to the next tuple(index of next is a number in tuple) and receive 'message' string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the prettiest, but you'd do this with `enumerate` + `sorted`.

```
>>> [(x[1][0], x[0]) for x in sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1][-1])]
[('g', 3), ('m', 4), ('s', 5), ('e', 1), ('e', 2), ('s', 6), ('a', 0)]
```